# How to draw circle in PCoA results?

Tags: r, vegan

[image]

I have results with `PC1` and `PC2` for all the samples, so that I can draw a scatter plot using `PC1` as x and `PC2` as y.

Now the samples are labeled by another variable, let's say `type` indicating which sample is case or control. How can I draw a plot as above, with circles covering the responding `type`.

Actually, I am using `vegan` package. I can draw a plot with `metaMDS` and `ordiplot`, but don't know how to make a circle as above. I have tried to read the tutorial, but still have no idea.

Comment: As it stands, this looks like a tool request. While it wasn't hard to find data and plot it, I would suggest you add at least the code you use and when you get stuck to make it a legitimate SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to draw this with `ade4`.

```
xy <- cbind.data.frame(x = runif(200, -1, 1), y = runif(200, -1, 1))
posi <- factor(xy$x > 0) : factor(xy$y > 0)
coul <- c("black", "red", "green", "blue")

library(ade4)
pca <- princomp(xy)
s.class(pca$scores[, 1:2], fac = posi, cell = 2, axesell = FALSE, csta = 0, col = coul, clabel = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I dived into what was `ape4`, I got to know there was a `ordihull` in `vegan` package, which can make the circles I need.

Comment: Hello, Roman, are you still there? I am using the `ade4`, it is exactly what I wanted. But how to draw `xlab` and `ylab`using the original axis data?

Comment: @Ming try experimenting with `axis()`.

Comment: Thanks, Roman, I can draw either `x` or  `y` axis using the`axis()`, but still can not edit the `xlab`. As in `plot(...,xlab="PC1",ylab="PC2")`, how to do that since I have generated a plot using `s.class`

Comment: @Ming you could try fiddling with `mtext`.